# sent downloadable http requests to zip

Tags: c#

I hope anyone can help me, I'am new in C, I am working on making web APIs that sends files from server based on an input , When I enter an ID , I get all files related to that ID (Indesign files, jpegs, pngs, illustator files ...)
I use Postman to get the resulat and it looks like the attached file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57h7r.png) :

I have to copy each link and paste it to address bar to download the file.

What I want is to have only one file (Zip) that contains all files.
Is that even doable ? Thanks

Comment: yes you can do that. Have a new controller action which collects all the files together, makes a zip file (you can google the code libraries you need to do that) and sends the zip file for download. How you specify which files should be included is for you to decide according to your requirements. Good luck. You can ask a better question once you've done some research and actually made an attempt - if you then have a specific coding problem for us to solve we'll happily help with it.

Comment: P.S. C != C# (and also != C++)

Comment: I apologize in C#

Comment: Thank you @ADyson  , I have already the controller that gets the file from server, should I make new controller for the zip or include it into my exiting controller ?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and it's returning a zipfile with the correct files, the issue now that these files have 0Kb size , Help please ?
Here's my code
 ``
            MemoryStream archiveStream = new MemoryStream();

```
        using (ZipArchive archiveFile = new ZipArchive(archiveStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (var item in assetsNotDuplicated)
            {
                // create file streams
                // add the stream to zip file

                var entry = archiveFile.CreateEntry(item.Name);

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
                {
                    sw.Write(item.Url);
                }
            }
        }


        HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        responseMsg.Content = new ByteArrayContent(archiveStream.ToArray());


        //archiveStream.Dispose();
        responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = "allfiles.zip" };
            responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");

            return responseMsg;
    }
```